# Google Maps API: GClientGeocoder.getLatLng()

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-2

I'm using the jQuery plugin http://googlemaps.mayzes.org/ for Google Maps but have had trouble adding markers.

Current setup:

Show AJAX content in a thickbox, where a map is loaded. The map loads fine, and centers properly to a geocoded address.

However, if you add a marker with a geocoded address the Google Maps API errors out with "a is undefined"

(relevant code from the plugin)

```
  if ( markers[i].geocode ) {
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLatLng(markers[i].geocode, function(center) {                    
      if (!center) 
        alert(address + " not found");
      else 
        jQuery.googleMaps.marker[i] = new GMarker(center, {draggable: markers[i].draggable, icon: gIcon});
    });
  }
```

The notable part is `geocoder.getLatLng(markers[i].geocode, func...` as this is directly calling the maps API, and upon inspection, `markers[i].geocode` is coming out as my test address ("Australia").

What I'm finding is that if I load the map the first time, it will center the map, but error due to the marker (and not show the UI either). If I close the thickbox and load it up again with a different address/country, the map will load fine, with the UI and centered on the new location *with a marker in the old address/country*.

Closing and opening the thickbox multiple times after this will move the centering, but the marker will always stay in the first address/country.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix, not necessarily a solution. The iterator goes over `markers.length`. I have no idea why and based off of the loop definition it shouldn't. If the `iterator==markers.length` I subtract `markers.length` from the iterator to reset it to `0` to re-loop over the markers.

I moved the overlay call into both the latitude/longitude and geocode if statements.  Only when `geocoder.getLatLng` finds an address should it add the overlay.

I'm still cleaning up the code and testing. Hopefully this helps.

```
mapMarkers: function(center, markers) {
        if ( typeof(markers.length) == 'undefined' )
            // One marker only. Parse it into an array for consistency.
            markers = [markers];        
        var j = 0;
        for ( indx = 0; indx<markers.length; indx++) {
            var gIcon = null;
            if ( markers[indx].icon ) {
                gIcon = $.googleMaps.mapMarkersOptions(markers[indx].icon);
            }

            if ( markers[indx].geocode ) {
                var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                geocoder.getLatLng(markers[indx].geocode, function(center) {                                        
                    if (!center) 
                        alert(address + " not found");
                    else 
                        if(true) //if(indx<markers.length || indx>markers.length)
                            {
                            if(indx==markers.length)
                                indx = indx-markers.length;

                                alert(center);
                                $.googleMaps.marker[indx] = new GMarker(center, {draggable: markers[indx].draggable, icon: gIcon});
                                $.googleMaps.gMap.addOverlay($.googleMaps.marker[indx]);
                                if ( markers[indx].info ) {
                                    // Hide Div Layer With Info Window HTML
                                    $(markers[indx].info.layer).hide();
                                    // Marker Div Layer Exists
                                    if ( markers[indx].info.popup )
                                        // Map Marker Shows an Info Box on Load
                                        $.googleMaps.marker[indx].openInfoWindowHtml($(markers[indx].info.layer).html());
                                    else
                                        $.googleMaps.marker[indx].bindInfoWindowHtml( $(markers[indx].info.layer).html().toString() );
                                }
                            }
                });

            }
            else if ( markers[indx].latitude && markers[indx].longitude ) {
                // Latitude & Longitude Center Point
                center = $.googleMaps.mapLatLong(markers[indx].latitude, markers[indx].longitude);
                $.googleMaps.marker[indx] = new GMarker(center, {draggable: markers[indx].draggable, icon: gIcon});
                $.googleMaps.gMap.addOverlay($.googleMaps.marker[indx]);
                if ( markers[indx].info ) {
                    // Hide Div Layer With Info Window HTML
                    $(markers[indx].info.layer).hide();
                    // Marker Div Layer Exists
                    if ( markers[indx].info.popup )
                        // Map Marker Shows an Info Box on Load
                        $.googleMaps.marker[indx].openInfoWindowHtml($(markers[indx].info.layer).html());
                    else
                        $.googleMaps.marker[indx].bindInfoWindowHtml( $(markers[indx].info.layer).html().toString() );
                }
            }

        }
    },
```